# Jquery Slider refuses to reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am currently a starter in query and trying to make a carousel, it works so far, but continues on after the slides and refuses to reset to the first slide after all slides have been moved, means my margin goes into endless numbers. This is what I have so far: 
         `

```
var timeout;
          var currentSlide = 1;
          var slideWidth = $('.slide').width();
          var slideGroup = $('#slider').children('.slide-group');
          var slides = $(slideGroup).find('.slide');


 var hmm = $(slides).length;
    console.log(hmm);
    function move(newSlide) {

    autoMove();

    if($(slideGroup).is(':animated') || currentSlide === newSlide) {
        return;
   }
    if(newSlide > currentSlide) {
       $(slideGroup).animate({'margin-left': '-='+slideWidth}, 1000);

    }
        if(newSlide === 0) {

        $(slideGroup).css({'margin-left': 0});
    }       
        };



    function autoMove(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if(currentSlide < ($(slides).length -1)){
                move(currentSlide +1)
            }if(currentSlide > ($(slides).length -1)) {
                move(0);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
    move();`
```

Comment: try setting to  move(1); instead of  move(0)

Comment: that doesn't solve it.

Comment: sum your all slides width and if they are greater than total send set margin-left to zero again

Comment: Could you give me your CSS? I'm trying to make it work here.